# Trigger script on Google calendar event

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I want to trigger some script when new calendar event is created in Google Calendar (say calling some rest API that enters event information to my database). I do not want any kind of UI that triggers the script. 
 Is it possible to achieve this using Google gadget since I do not want any UI? I would really appreciate the help as I am new to Google API.

Thanks a lot 
Shubhra

Answer (score 2):

[Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) has something like notifications. See this link: [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push). From documentation:

> The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch
>   for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the
>   performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra
>   network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine
>   if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google
>   Calendar API notifies your application.

Comment: I have gone through push notification documentation, But still having issue while request a watch on calendar events from python api. Would you help to achieve this using python api.

Comment: The API only supports calling a URL when a calendar event is **added** or **changed**, not when one is *due*.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar API ([relevant docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)) provides a `watch` endpoint that allows you to specify a webhook upon certain events.

To set up the webhook, you can call the Calendar API endpoint a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/watch` with the body

```
{
  "id": string
  "type": string,
  "address": string
}
```

The `"address"` field tells Calendar what endpoint to call when there is a new Calendar event. You'll need to create and host this endpoint yourself.

Another option is to use a service like **Zapier**, which has [fantastic integrations for Google Calendar](https://zapier.com/apps/google-calendar/integrations) and makes setting up a listener (i.e. a trigger) and corresponding action very simple.