# Checking to see if calendar has changed using google calendar API

Tags: python, calendar, google-calendar-api, flags

I'm using the google calendar API (python) to do some calendar parsing, and I'm going to be running a script once an hour to download events for the next two weeks. I'm on a pretty old system which has a lot going on so I want to only pull when there has been data changed. Is there any flag within the api to check if there is a change since last read?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [`Events: watch`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) method which watches for changes to Events resources. Also, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301918/trigger-script-on-google-calendar-event), the Google Calendar API provides [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) that let you watch for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google Calendar API notifies your application.